# ValueError: "port" must be None or a string, not <class 'int'>

Tags: python, python-3.x, serial-port

I am trying to issue commands to my usb connected lock controller. The code runs fine until this line:

```
Connected ports: 
['COM6']
Please enter the port number that has port connected. 
 i.e. if COM3 is shown, enter 3 when ask to enter port number. 
 If the above shows [] than no connected port is found and errors will follow
Please enter the port number: 6
```

and the following error came up:

```
ValueError: "port" must be None or a string, not <class 'int'>
```

I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "[...]", line 44, in <module>
    serial_connection() #executes the function defined above

  File "[...]", line 29, in serial_connection
    ser.port = COMPORT - 1 #counter for port name starts at 0

  File "[...]", line 260, in port
    raise ValueError('"port" must be None or a string, not {}'.format(type(port)))
```

Below is the code:

```
#this library is required as it helps establish the serial connection
#Using  pyserial Library to establish connection
import serial #not being used because it was already called in portRead
from portRead import *

#Global Variables
ser = 0

#this will print out the port that can be used; ports that are connected. i.e. if COM3 is shown, enter 3 when ask to enter port number
#if shown [] then no usb is connected to a port and errors will follow
if __name__ == '__main__':
    print ("Connected ports: ") #print means printing information on screen
    print(serial_ports()) #function derived from portRead
    print("Please enter the port number that has port connected. \n "
          "i.e. if COM3 is shown, enter 3 when ask to enter port number. \n If the above shows [] than no connected port is found and errors will follow")

#defining the serial connection
def serial_connection():
    while True: #the while loop is used to continuously ask you to issue a new command until you decide to quit the program
        ser = serial.Serial()
        ser.baudrate = 38400 #Suggested rate in Southco documentation, both locks and program MUST be at same rate
        COMPORT = int(input("Please enter the port number: ")) #this refers to which port your usb is inserted into
        ser.port = COMPORT - 1 #counter for port name starts at 0

        print ('Port %d entered Stephan '%COMPORT)
        #timeout in seconds
        ser.timeout = 10
        ser.open()
        command = input("please type command - open1/close1, or open2/close2. \n"
                    "If already open and you try to open no action will be taken and vice-versa...: \n ")
        #call the serial_connection() function
        ser.write(("%s\r\n"%command).encode('ascii')) #Southco locks receives and sends commands in ASCII


serial_connection() #executes the function defined above
```

Comment: I suppose you should set port to `"COM{}".format(COMPORT)` instead of the number.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. Where would i incorporate that?

Comment: You could probably just remove `int` from `int(input("..."))`

Comment: but then i would have to subscrat 1 from the result, and i cant compare int to str

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you have to specify the port *name* in `ser.port` as a *string*, not just the number (as I guess it could be `PRN`, not only `COMx`).

fix suggestion:

```
COMPORT = int(input("Please enter the port number: ")) #this refers to which port your usb is inserted into
ser.port = "COM{}".format(COMPORT-1)
```

check the doc: https://pythonhosted.org/pyserial/shortintro.html#opening-serial-ports